# Solidity state variable resets to default inside function

Tags: storage, struct, memory, constructor

For this project, I am coding smart contracts for Ethereum using Solidity.

In the following code, the variable `numCertificates` should initially be 1. Nonetheless, newCertificateId is 0 when assigned. According to the debugger (I'm using remix.ethereum.org), for some reason, numCertificates becomes 0 as soon as the line where newCertificateId is assigned is reached.

I have played around with remix a lot, and according to it, numCertificates is 1 until exactly the aforementioned line is reached. Also, I think that if I modify numCertificates in another function, the variable stays the same as before.

My attempts at trying to figure this out lead me to believe that when I access numCertificates, I am not accessing the public state variable but something else.

Why does this code have this problem and how can it be solved?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract MyToken {

    struct Certificate {
      uint64 certificateId;
      uint64 meterId;

      uint32 timestamp;
      uint48 value;
      address[] owners;

      mapping (address => uint48) ownershipSplit;

      bool burned;
    }

    mapping (uint64 => Certificate) public certificates;
    uint64 numCertificates = 1;

    function MyToken() public {
      // ... irrelevant stuff
    }

    function produceCertificate(
      uint64 meterId,
      uint32 timestamp,
      uint48 value,
      address owner
      ) public {
        // Create the certificate in memory
        numCertificates;// only for debbuging
        Certificate storage newCertificate = constructCertificate(meterId, timestamp, carbonMitigationValue, owner);
        uint64 newCertificateId = numCertificates;
        newCertificate.certificateId = newCertificateId;

        // Save the certificate
        certificates[newCertificateId] = newCertificate;
        numCertificates++;
    }

    function constructCertificate(
      uint64 meterId,
      uint32 timestamp,
      uint48 value,
      address owner
      ) internal returns (Certificate storage newCertificate) {
        newCertificate.meterId = meterId;
        newCertificate.timestamp = timestamp;
        newCertificate.value = value;

        newCertificate.owners.push(owner);
        newCertificate.ownershipSplit[owner] = value;

        newCertificate.burned = false; // by default new certificates are fresh

        return newCertificate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is difficult to help here because your code is incomplete and is not possible to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Jaime The code posted reproduces the issue

Comment: No, the struct Certificate is not defined

Comment: @Jaime My bad you are right, adding the details right now

Comment: @Jaime I added the parameters of produceCertificate and the Certificate struct

Comment: take a look at my answer and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be the use of storage pointier that you are doing. I can not understand what are you pointing at when you use:

```
Certificate storage newCertificate = constructCertificate(meterId, timestamp, Value, owner);
```

I changed your code to this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract MyToken {

    struct Certificate {
      uint64 certificateId;
      uint64 meterId;
      uint32 timestamp;
      uint48 value;
      address[] owners;
      mapping (address => uint48) ownershipSplit;
      bool burned;
    }

    mapping (uint64 => Certificate) public certificates;
    uint64 public numCertificates = 1;

    function MyToken() public {
      // ... irrelevant stuff
    }

    function produceCertificate(
      uint64 meterId,
      uint32 timestamp,
      uint48 value,
      address owner
      ) public {
        // Create the certificate in memory
        //numCertificates;// only for debbuging
        Certificate storage newCertificate = certificates[numCertificates];
        newCertificate.meterId = meterId;
        newCertificate.timestamp = timestamp;
        newCertificate.value = value;
        newCertificate.owners.push(owner);
        newCertificate.ownershipSplit[owner] = value;
        newCertificate.burned = false; // by default new certificates are fresh
        newCertificate.certificateId = numCertificates;
        numCertificates= numCertificates +1;
    }

}
```

In this code, you define a pointer to the structure that is the mapping, in the position indicated by `numCertificates` (which actually the Id of the new certificate).

Therefore the changes to `newCertficate` are actually changes made to `certificates[numCertificates]` directly.

Note that I removed the function `produceCertificate` for simplicity.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why the uninitialized storage pointer cause the problems?

Comment: probably the memory positions of the variables in the structure were overlapping with the variables that you defined initially.